# How to get all files in a directory with certain extension in C#?

Tags: c#, file

I am using this to get all files in a directory:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory_);
```

But is there a way to get all files that end with "jpg" in one line without doing an

```
if (file.endswidth("jpg")
```

check?

Comment: this will fail if the file extension is JPG. All caps. So not a good practice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Directory.GetFiles (sourceDirectory_, "*.jpg")
```

See the [MSDN docs for this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) for more details.

Comment: this will fail, if the extension is JPG. Not a good practice.

Comment: Um? Since when does Windows do case-sensitive filename comparisons?

Comment: As Pontus says, this method is case-insensitive. I've just checked it with exactly the situation you describe, prashant_sp - it picked up "a.jpg" and "b.JPG" with no problems.

Answer (score 4):

You can provide the search pattern as a second parameter to GetFiles:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory_, "*.jpg");
```